# Is it possible to customize the perforce commands?

Tags: perforce

I am new to perforce is it possible to modify or add new features in perforce commands with the help of Perforce API's

Answer (score 3):

The Perforce APIs more or less copy the command set that you see when you run `p4 help commands` on the command-line. There isn't much to gain by merely moving from the command-line (or P4V) to the API.

Having said that, you can always use the existing command set as building blocks for more complicated functionality. That can be achieved by scripting (where you combine multiple commands of the `p4` command-line) or by programming (where you combine multiple APIs to higher-level functionality).

What kind of a feature are you after?

Answer (score 0):

Much can be achieved by using `p4 aliases`.

An example from [here](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.2/manuals/cmdref/chapter.introduction.html#introduction.aliases) will create a new changelist. More interesting applications can be found on that page.

```
newChange $(desc) = change -o > $(chg) &&
                   p4subst "$(LT)enter.*$(GT)" $(desc) < $(chg) > $(chg2) &&
                   change -i < $(chg2)
```